# NSURL Encoding issue

Tags: ios

In my project I am communicating with the moudule via usb with ios device, and in my app I am calling the webservice to get the module diagram based on the selected configuration.
 Here is the url.,  **http://mycompurl.php?message=message&color=blue&client=ipad&radio=Pioneer&make=Chevrolet&model=Cobalt&year=2008&option=none** and when that screen directly with out connecting the module it is working fine showing respected image but when go to that screen after connected with module the url changes like **http://mycompurl.php?message=message&color=blue&client=ipad&radio=Pioneer&make=Chevrolet&model=Cobalt%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00&year=2008&option=none** this. so it not working. I don't know why it is adding %00 to the model.

Thanks in advance

```
url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

I am using URL like this

Comment: Going to need more code, isn't there a delegate callback when something is connected? Probably should start there

Comment: More code, where do you get `urlString`? Also `NSLog()` `urlString` and 'url'

Comment: %00 is a NULL character that has been percent escaped by stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding. Check your urlString, in particular that model= component

Comment: we are not getting the any value fromthe module, we are getting that vehicle data from the web service, and I am getting this issue with the all models

Comment: Hey CSmith, Thanks for your reply. Currently I am using the NSASCIIStringEncoding for url encoding and I changed that to NSUTF8StringEncoding then it is working. I got this doubt because of you only. Thank you once again. and +1 to your reply

Comment: Hey sorry guys, when I changed to NSUTF8StringEncoding, it worked two or three times only. Again I am seeing the same issue. Can you guys have any idea please